# How do json information differ from the usual examples?

Tags: javascript, json, url, google-sheets

```
function myFunction(){

  var url = "https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var code = json["candleDateTime"];
  Logger.log(code);

}
```

I'm trying to execute the above code.

Unlike other JSON information, URL starts with []

I do not know how to handle this.

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Your url starts with what? And what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Do you mean the response you're getting back from the URL is wrapped with "[]"?  The url you're accessing is returning json as it appears it should.

Comment: The beginning and end of url are clogged with [].

var code = json ["candleDateTime"]; does not seem to work.

If we do not have [], we know it will simply be treated as "".

I want to know how to deal with [].

Comment: The response from the URL is an array. So when you retrieve the value of ``candleDateTime`` from the response, how about modifying to ``var code = json[0]["candleDateTime"]``?